# How can I use the State monad effectively in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, monads

I have written a simple fibonacci function in Haskell that uses the State monad to save solutions to overlapping sub-problems. Now despite the function working I am not really happy with the solution, especially with the last map lookup. How can I improve my solution? Thank you.

```hs
module Lib (
    fib
) where

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe

type DP = Map Int Int

fib :: Int -> State DP Int
fib 0 = return 1
fib 1 = return 1
fib x = do
    solved <- get
    let m = Map.lookup x solved
    case m of
            Nothing -> do
                prev1 <- fib (x - 1)
                prev2 <- fib (x - 2)  
                put $ Map.insert x (prev1 + prev2) solved
            Just value -> put $ Map.insert x value solved
    gets (fromMaybe 0 . Map.lookup x)
```

Comment: I might do a full review later, but the biggest issue I see is that here you overwrite the insertions from the two lines above at this point `put $ Map.insert x (prev1 + prev2) solved`.

Comment: @Franky I am not sure I follow you. :( The two lines above `put $ Map.insert x (prev1 + prev2) solved` just get the `Int` result from calling `fib` and then I just save the result on the `Map Int Int`. Now the `Just value -> put $ Map.insert x value solved` is doing an unnecessary write on the Map but I wasn't sure how to write it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be reviewing this code for efficiency, since I'm not quite so comfortable with analyzing some combination of State monad, immutable data structures, and laziness.

However, there are a few obvious changes you can make to your code.

## Passing State Properly

This is what Franky was getting at with his comment, and it's a bit of a tricky bug. When you do

```
put $ Map.insert x (prev1 + prev2) solved
```

you use the `solved` that you get at the beginning of the function invocation. But your recursion goes from top-to-bottom, so if you're computing `fib 10`, `solved` is the empty map when you are getting the final answer. Essentially, your memo map keeps getting overwritten with maps that have less information. The fix is pretty easy.

```
prev1 <- fib (x - 1)
prev2 <- fib (x - 2)
solved' <- get
put $ Map.insert x (prev1 + prev2) solved'
```

Just get the updated state after the recursive invocations.

## Naming

I think `solved` is ambiguous as to whether it refers to a single solution or the memo map. I would call it something like `solutions`, maybe `sols` or `fibs` if you feel like abbreviating. In light of the previous bug, you may wish to call the first one `initialSolutions` and later ones `updatedSolutions` or something like that (I just used `solutions` and `solutions'`).

The name `m` is OK, but it doesn't really need to exist at all. You can just case on `Map.lookup x solved` directly instead of binding `m` and then casing on it.

## The `case` Statement

It seems like you're trying to use the `case` statement to set up your memo map so that it always has a value for `x`. There are two things to address about this.

### Indexing

If you, the programmer, are sure that `x` exists in the map (and in the `case` above you guarantee it), you could instead use the unsafe lookup `Map.!`. Given the option between returning an erroneous value silently (your `fromMaybe 0`) and crashing and burning in case of a bug, I would generally prefer the latter. So your last line would look something like `gets (Map.! x)`.

### The Last Lookup

However, doing the lookup itself is inelegant. It *might* make sense if there was a lot of convoluted stuff happening between, but proper indexing doesn't get checked by the type system and doing a lookup takes (not much, but some) extra time. Fortunately, you don't need to do it. Since I'm going to assume you're learning Haskell, consider how you'd approach a similar problem in an imperative language. What would you do to change this code:

```
if (x in solutions):
  solutions[x] = solutions[x]
else:
  prev1 = fib(x-1)
  prev2 = fib(x-2)
  solutions[x] = prev1 + prev2
return solutions[x]
```

There are many right answers, but one thing you can do is as follows (this particular code is nice because it avoids extra lookups):

```
if (x in solutions):
  return solutions[x]
else:
  prev1 = fib(x-1)
  prev2 = fib(x-2)
  solution = prev1 + prev2
  solutions[x] = solution
  return solution
```

Your `case` statement functions like the imperative `if` statement, except more powerful since you have guarantees on the types! So mirroring the imperative's revision, you can revise your code like so

```
case Map.lookup x solved of
        Just solution -> return solution
        Nothing -> do
            prev1 <- fib (x - 1)
            prev2 <- fib (x - 2)
            solutions' <- get
            let solution = prev1 + prev2
            put $ Map.insert x solutions' solved
            return solution
```

Now you don't need the last lookup. Notice how we also avoid the issue entirely of whether `x` is in `solutions`, because we explicitly handle the case where it is and isn't. This code doesn't have any unsafe lookups!

### Addendum on Lookups

Now, even if you wanted to make your `case` statement only fill out the memo map instead of also returning the answers, I agree with you that you are doing unnecessary work.

```
Just value -> put $ Map.insert x value solved
```

The line above needlessly reinserts the value of `x`. The memo map already has `x`, and `x` is already set to `value`. If you wanted to otherwise keep your code the same, at least change this to

```
Just value -> return ()
```

`put` has type `a -> State a ()`. It's a convention for monads to pass `()` as their return value if they perform an action that doesn't return anything (like how `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()`). You can simply `return ()` to do nothing instead of actually modifying the memo map, which I assume you did to fix a type error.

## Revised Function

Included are comments noting the revision

```hs
fib :: Int -> State DP Int
fib 0 = return 1
fib 1 = return 1
fib x = do
    -- Change to a more descriptive name
    solutions <- get
    -- Case directly on the value without intermediate variable
    case Map.lookup x solutions of
            Nothing -> do
                prev1 <- fib (x - 1)
                prev2 <- fib (x - 2)
                -- Get updated solutions
                solutions' <- get
                let solution = prev1 + prev2
                put $ Map.insert x solution solutions'
                -- Return solution directly
                return solution
            Just solution ->
                -- Return solution directly
                return solution
    -- Elide previous lookup
```